# how to resize the size of a control automatically when the size of the form changes

Tags: c#, winforms

I am drawing a rectangle on my form and on top of that I have a label that I dragged. Now I want to re-size the rectangle that contains label so that it changes automatically when the size of the form is changed(maximized and all). 
I tried using

```
this.label1.Size = new Size();
```

but this causes my label or may be rectangle to disappeared from the form. I cannot see it in my form now.
Anchor and Dock properties do not serve my purpose. I have to hard code it.
Need help on how to solve this resizing problem.

Comment: What's the problem with the Anchor and Dock properties? They're the standard way of setting up layouts in Windows Forms.

Comment: I forgot to mention here that i am drawing a rectangle here and on top of that i have the label. that's why i need to resize the rectangle that contains label. so anchor and dock wont work. Sorry for inconvenience

Comment: Are you hand-drawing the rectangle?  You could use a Panel control with it's border set and place your label inside that.  The you can use the standard layout properties Anchor/Dock to have them automatically size with the form.

Comment: Yes i am hand drawing the rectangle.

Comment: So could you replace your hand-drawn rectangle with a panel?  If it's a simple shape then you can use the Panel and have less code to manage.

Comment: Rectangle is what i need in my code and not a panel.

Comment: @ghd could you explain a bit more why you need a rectangle in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Use the .Anchor property.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) and [Dock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx) properties.  They should be able to provide you with the functionality that you need.

You could also look in to using the [.SetBounds()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setbounds.aspx) method in the resize event.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `Dock` property of the control which allows you to make it align with the left, right, top or bottom edge of the form or fill the entire form.

Or use `Anchor` property, which allows you to anchor the coordinates - e.g. when you set anchor to left, right, top, bottom, it will resize with the form.

Comment: I cannot use it. I have to hardcode my code according to my needs. Anchor and Dock do not serve the purpose

Answer (score 0):

If Dock and Anchor are no good then just set the Width and Height properties. By creating a default Size object and assigning that to your control you are basically assigning Width and Height to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the `SizeChanged` event:

```
this.SizeChanged += new EventHandler(Form1_SizeChanged);
```

then in the envent handler method, you must arrange `Size` and `Location` of your control:

```
void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   myControl.Size = new Size(w,h);  // size of the control
   myControl.Location = new Point(x,y);  //coordinates from the upperleft corner of your control's container (the form in your case)
}
```

N.B.
AFAIK a label cannot be resized as you want (instead location is ok), because has a fixed size. Use textbox with `Readonly` and `Multiline` properties set to true

Comment: label size can be changes ..by changing the Font Size !
label1.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 24);

Comment: @Sunny: that's different. In that case the size automatically computed according to the font size, not set by the user...

Answer (score 0):

Try [**form `Scale()` method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.scale.aspx). But for me, it has a little strange behavior...